# Condicion usando un array

Tags: javascript, html5

estuve intentado hacer una condicion que diga cual es el helado mas caro que puedo comprar con el dinero que tenga, Por si acaso, yo se hacer este codigo con puros if, pero queria ver si se podia recortar un poco mas el codigo con una buena condicion y usando un arreglo

coflaUSD = prompt('Cuanto dinero tienes Cofla?');

```
coflaUSD = parseInt(coflaUSD);

const helados = [ 
    { nombre: 'Palito de helado de agua', precio: 0.6},
    { nombre: 'Palito de helado de crema', precio: 1},
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Heladix', precio: 1.6},
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Heladovich', precio: 1.7},
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Helardo', precio: 1.8},
    { nombre: 'Pote de helado con confites', precio: 2.9},
    { nombre: 'Pote helado de 1/4 KG', precio: 2.9},
]


for (let i = 0; i < helados.length; i++) {
    if (coflaUSD >= helados[i].precio && coflaUSD < helados[helados.length + 1].precio){
        alert(`comprate el ${helados[i].nombre}`);
    } else {
        alert('Comprate el pote de helado con confites o el de 1/4 KG');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, pon un titulo que indique que tipo de problema tenes. Y aparte de eso, cual es el problema que tenes?

Comment: ¿Cuál  es el error que tienes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método **find** de los arreglos y previamente ordenar el arreglo de helados segun el costo de mayor a menor, es allí donde puedes buscar el primer helado cuyo precio sea menor o igual al dinero que tienes.

Con todo eso un ejemplo sería así:

```js
const dineroActual = 2.0
const helados = [
    { nombre: 'Palito de helado de agua', precio: 0.6 },
    { nombre: 'Palito de helado de crema', precio: 1 },
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Heladix', precio: 1.6 },
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Heladovich', precio: 1.7 },
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Helardo', precio: 1.8 },
    { nombre: 'Pote de helado con confites', precio: 2.9 },
    { nombre: 'Pote helado de 1/4 KG', precio: 2.9 },
]

helados.sort((a, b) => b.precio - a.precio)
const heladoMasCaro = helados.find(helado => helado.precio <= dineroActual)

if (heladoMasCaro) {
    console.log(`Comprate el helado de ${heladoMasCaro.nombre}`);
} else {
    console.log('No tienes suficiente dinero para un helado');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma un poco más larga pero más rápida ya que te ahorras el tiempo de ejecución de ordenar el arreglo es:

```js
const dineroActual = 2.0
const helados = [
    { nombre: 'Palito de helado de agua', precio: 0.6 },
    { nombre: 'Palito de helado de crema', precio: 1 },
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Heladix', precio: 1.6 },
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Heladovich', precio: 1.7 },
    { nombre: 'Bombon marca Helardo', precio: 1.8 },
    { nombre: 'Pote de helado con confites', precio: 2.9 },
    { nombre: 'Pote helado de 1/4 KG', precio: 2.9 },
]

let heladoMasCaro = { precio: 0 }
helados.forEach((helado) => {
    if (helado.precio > heladoMasCaro.precio && helado.precio <= dineroActual)
        heladoMasCaro = helado
})

if (heladoMasCaro.precio > 0) {
    console.log(`Comprate el helado de ${heladoMasCaro.nombre}`);
} else {
    console.log('No tienes suficiente dinero para un helado');
}
```